# how to initize late variable in flutter? LateInitializationError

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an initialization error of my variable **late Future<List?> listTest;**. I understand that I have an error because I try to use the variable inside a futureBuilder but it has not yet been initialized. I tried to make the variable nullable (**Future<List?>? listTest;**), giving no more compilation error, but not working in my case.

Searching the internet I saw that I have to initialize it within the void initState, but I didn't understand how to do that. Can anybody help me?
Piece of code:

```
late Future<List<CursoTO>?> listTest;

void initState() {
  super.initState();

  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
    setState(() {
      final routeArgs1 =
          ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;


    var curso = Curso();
    listTest= curso.lista(
        nomeImagem!,
        idSite!);
     });
   });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var futureBuilder = FutureBuilder(
      future: listTest,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.hasData) {
           return createScreen(context, snapshot);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
           return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
         },
        );
    return Scaffold(
        body: futureBuilder);
   }
```

Comment: You are not assigning `listTest` a value anywhere in your code so the error will occur for sure. Remove the `late` keyword because it's not needed if the value is nullable. `late` is useful when you want to access instance members for the assignment or if you want to assign the value within the `initState`

Comment: sorry, I've corrected the question now, I'm assigning listTest= curso.lista. And **late** so it wouldn't be necessary if I did Future<List<CursoTO>?>? listTest; however if I do that, ListTest is always null and the code remains in CircularProgress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a syntactical perspective (I can't test your code), there's no need to use the keyword `late` as you're handling the various states of this object in the builder function already. Simply initialise an empty list then update it in the `initState()` method.

```dart
// late Future<List<CursoTO>?> listTest;
Future<List<CursoTO>?> listTest = Future.value([]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize listTest in constructor.
Otherwise make you variable to static and initialize with empty list and aging put value in initstate